# Copy constructor shortcut

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a class with about 50 members. 1 of them is a pointer. So, naturally I have to make my own copy constructor, copy everything and create a new instance of that object. My question is: Is there a shortcut or some special way I can have everything copied (like the default copy constructor does) then just handle that one pointer? Rather than manually copying each member.

Comment: 50 members! Have a look at this: http://objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd wrap your pointer into a helper class that does the copy in the way you like. That way you can leave the big class with the default copy ctor.

Comment: Amusingly, I wrote such a class to support the Pimpl idiom effortlessly. It's not necessarily an easy class to craft, but once done, you can reuse it wherever :D

Comment: Alternatively, you can put all of the non-pointer data into its own struct, and just copy construct that.

Comment: @JamesKanze A good goal is to have the most of your code free from hand-written destructors, copy/move constructors, operators=, and destructors. If you encapsulate your semantics into small, generic smart pointer or resource handler classes, then you can easily get the auto-generated constructors, destructors and operators to do what you want - cleanly and consistently.

Comment: @Kos Why is that a good goal?  I've never particularly heard of it being a goal.  (In fact, a lot of coding guidelines I've seen require explicit copy and assignment even if they're empty.  It shows that you've thought about them, and it allows making them not inline.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a smart pointer instead, then rely on your class' default copy constructor.

Standard smart pointers (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`) don't have copy constructors that would copy their objects, but you can roll up your own.

Comment: `shared_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor?

Comment: it doesn't have a copy constructor that would copy the object (it copies the internal pointer and increments the reference counter)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that the default copy won't work I'll assume that your object owns the pointee.

If all you need is a shallow copy that cleans up properly, use `shared_ptr` from C++11 or boost.

If you need a deep copy, I would first suggest to store the contained object by values instead of by pointer. Then you get the copy for free and you don't have to worry about one extra set of memory management.

Finally if none of those are an option I'd write a pointer wrapper that handles deep copy semantics (I don't believe boost offers such a class).

Comment: Storing by value is the #1 option for implementing ownership, but it does put some limitations (like binding two objects' lifetime together, which isn't always desirable). A smart pointer acting like a value would be useful for some cases, probably for the OP's too. Strange that neither the standard lib nor boost have one.